# Eclipse for Java Developers, error in xml

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I have a problem with eclipse (for java developers). I try to do an app, but when i select a java file and i click "run", Eclipse give me this error. I rename my app "AndroidFAQ". So, it appear this problem:

"AndroidFAQ does not specify a android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner instrumentation or does not declare uses-library android.test.runner in its AndroidManifest.xml".
I tried some solutions but they didn't resolve it.... 
One of them there is this: 
**Add to the AndroidManifest.xml the following -

```
<instrumentation android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner" android:targetPackage="..." android:label="..." />
<uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />**
```

Maybe I was wrong, but this solution didn't resolve the problem... So when i write that it appare a pop up with an error in the xml...
Thanks for the answers!

Comment: What error is popped up?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. `<uses-library>` has to be inside the `<application>` element:

```
<instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.xxx.xxx" />

<application>
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>
```

Comment: the problem is when i write android:target and android:label... what i must write in xxx?

Comment: It should be full name of the package you're testing. android:label is in <application>.